# How do I reconfigure SQL Server Cluster if disk labels are changed?

Tags: sql-server, installation, cluster-computing

I have installed SQL Server Cluster 2016. After the installation, our Windows SA is going to re-lable the disks for the company standard. That means changing Disk D to L, L to D vice and versa. (D is for database data file, L is for database log file).

Since SQL Server Cluster is already installed, how do I reconfigure SQL Server Cluster?  I can always uninstall and reinstall SQL Server Cluster.  But it is kind of time consuming.

Is there a way to reconfigure SQL Server Cluster without re-install SQL Server Cluster?  Can I change the disk label via cluster failover manager without uninstall SQL Server Cluster and reinstall it from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility, but you need test first in UAT before applying on production as the storage dependencies may vary on your environment. To do so, you may want to follow these [steps..](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/04/10/sql-server-steps-to-migrate-cluster-storage-from-old-disks-to-newly-attached-disks/)

Comment: Thank, however my situation is that, Windows SA are not going to add any new disks.  Simply he is going to swap disk D with L and L with D (not adding any new disks)  Basically whatever on D drive will be copied over to L drive.  (Data file will be on L drive instead).  (Log file will be on D drive).  Some of the system database will be on D and L drive.

Comment: For example, for master database, D:\data\master.mdf will become L:\data\master.mdf and vice versa.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider changing path in **SQL Service - Startup parameters** for `master` and `SQL Error log`

Comment: Consider **Step 7** and **Step 9**, steps from same source has been summarized in DBA SE: dba.stackexchange.com/a/245598/185080